# How to get fixed-pitch code blocks in variable-pitch Spacemacs org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, fonts, spacemacs, font-lock, literate-programming

I like to use variable-pitch mode when working with prose in org-mode, but I have to turn it off when I involve tables or code blocks. Using answers found elsewhere, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758139/variable-pitch-for-org-mode-fixed-pitch-for-tables I can obtain what I am looking for in vanilla Emacs.

My issue is that this does not work with the code blocks in Spacemacs. Spacemacs seems to add font-lock'd faces to code blocks, and I do not know how to make only these faces stay fixed-pitch while the rest of the buffer is in variable-pitch-mode. Would anyone have any advice?

I currently use the following Spacemacs layers:

```
 auto-completion
 better-defaults
 emacs-lisp
 git
 markdown
 org
 (shell :variables
        shell-default-height 30
        shell-default-position 'bottom)
 spell-checking
 syntax-checking
```

[image: A screenshot of Spacemacs entirely in fixed-pitch mode.]

[image: A screenshot of Spacemacs entirely in variable-pitch mode.]

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the faces `org-block-background` and `org-table`, respectively, and set a fixed-width font foundry.

Comment: From my understanding, org-block-background was removed from org-mode in this commit: http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/commit/?id=f8b42e8 Has it been re-added? I don't seem to have it.

Comment: However, customizing org-table does indeed make tables fix-pitched.

Comment: You're right, I was using the org-mode that came bundled with Emacs 24.5.